# Deploy django app with gunicorn and nginx. ERROR supervisor: child process was not spawned

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I'm trying to deploy my django app in a **digital ocean droplet**. I'm using **nginx and gunicorn** following [this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/14/how-to-deploy-to-digital-ocean.html)

This is how **gunicorn_start** looks like

```
    #!/bin/sh

    NAME="PlantArte"
    DIR=/home/paulauzca/PlantArte
    USER=paulauzca
    GROUP=paulauzca
    WORKERS=3
    BIND=unix:/home/paulauzca/run/gunicorn.sock
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings
    DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=project.wsgi
    LOG_LEVEL=error
    
    cd $DIR
    source ../bin/activate
    
    export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
    export PYTHONPATH=$DIR:$PYTHONPATH
    
    exec ../bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
       --name $NAME\
       --workers $WORKERS \
       --user=$USER \
       --group=$GROUP \
       --bind=$BIND \
       --log-level=$LOG_LEVEL \
       --log-file=-
```

This is **PlantArte.conf file**

```
#!/bin/sh
[program:PlantArte]
command=/home/paulauzca/bin/gunicorn_start --daemon
user=paulauzca
startsecs=0
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
environment=PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/paulauzca/bin/python
stdout_logfile=/home/paulauzca/logs/gunicorn-error.log
```

Following the tutorial I run `sudo supervisorctl status PlantArte`

And I always get

```
PlantArte                        RUNNING   pid 3566, uptime 0:00:00
```

**With 0 second runtime**. Which is weird. If I go into **gunicorn-error.log** I get

```
supervisor: couldn't exec /home/paulauzca/bin/gunicorn_start: EACCES
supervisor: child process was not spawned
```

I've tried the "solutions" to this problem I've found on the internet but there is not much information about this...